# React npm package to solve a Problem facing on my e-commerce website where I have to edit the image inside the image

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, package

I have a problem with a editing the image inside a image , its like a E-commerce where people can edit their mobile case,T-shirt logos,cups with their photo and bottle with there own photo and adding the text and shapes i want to store the image in the mongo db using the Filesystem with empress and the react , I'm trying to do with any NPM package i couldn't find it[These are the minimum requirments i need to edit the Image and i need to know how to give layouts also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfagh.jpg)

I tried the couple of NPM package but they didn't workout , I saw a youtube also but still didn't get enough knowledge to do it. I need to know the package which can help me to able to do the editing with these properties

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: im not able to start also how can i give the code